# Can I recover a file deleted by Ant?

Tags: ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need a program for recovering deleted files in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8297)

Is there a way to recover files deleted by [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant)?

I ran a script that deleted a file. However, it is not inside the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Using software like  [Restoration](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,23108-order,1/description.html), [Recover My Files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/) or any of the programs reviewed by [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/collection/collid,1295-order,1/files.html).